# Indent enumerate

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I want to indent my enumerate list. I found some suggestions online but my enumerate is more advanced (I think) than the ones online. How do I indent my list with say 0.5 cm? Here is a snippet of my report.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt, DIV=10]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text

\begin{document}

This is some text,
\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi},leftmargin=*] 
\item 1 step
\item 2 step
\item 3 step
\end{enumerate}
And some more text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? `enumitem` defines a `labelindent` key.

Comment aside, with `fourier`, you should load `erewhon`, a `utopia` clone, which has true smallcaps in all weight and shapes, superior and inferior figures (useful for footnotes) and some other features.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt, DIV=10]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

This is some text,
\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic*.,ref=Step \arabic*, leftmargin=*, labelindent =0.5cm]
\item 1 step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step step
\item 2 step
\item 3 step
\end{enumerate}
And some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]